# joining two models and show theme in one grid

Tags: atk4

I have two models:

**A) Model ticket:**

```
class Model_Ticket extends Model_Table {
    public $table='ticket';
    function init(){
        parent::init();

        $this->addField('subject');
        $this->addField('content')->type("text");
    }
}
```

**B) Subticket:**

```
class Model_Subticket extends Model_Table {
    public $table='subticket';
    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $this->addField('content')->type("text");
        $this->addField('ticket_id')->type("int");
    }
}
```

each ticket has many subtickets.
now I want to have a grid which the first row of that should be the "Content" of main ticket and other rows should be the "Content" of subtickets of that ticktet.

how can we do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First create the grid which would display sub tickets, load them properly etc. Next look inside Grid's `render()` method. As you follow the execution, you'll find the following call chain:

- [grid::render()](http://agiletoolkit.org/dox/html/class_grid___advanced.html#afde88292c44dc59faf017738dae6dffb)
- [CompleteLister::renderRows()](http://agiletoolkit.org/dox/html/class_complete_lister.html#a8cffb519cef8d77078eda50bec9f1496)
- CompleteLister::renderDataRows()

You would need to override the normal rendering, fill out $this->current_row yourself and then call renderDataRows once before passing execution to parent::renderRows();

This will pop an extra row inside your Grid.